# jQuery trigger not working inside of a Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a **jQuery** page and I'm trying to split up some of my code across different **Javascript** files, I'm trying to use **Events** to keep track of when I should do hide-show operations across different parts of my Form.

I have a `jQuery(document).ready` function that applies to the whole form and then I have other smaller **modules** where the events are not being bound, I tried inspecting the elements with **Firebug** to check if the events existed, the top event from the `jQuery(document).ready` exists but the other events from the modules do not.

```
jQuery(function(){
    
    // Get the Module
    var module_id = 20044;
    var module = EventHandler.getModule(module_id);

    // Data that should be sent as part of the Extra Lead
    var extras = [];

    // If a the given Module ID belongs to a defined Module
    if(module)
    {
        var $module = jQuery(module.identifier());
        var $form   = $module.closest('form');

        $form.on('brandsEnabled', function() {

            // THIS EVENT COMES FROM THE Document.Ready function and Works

        });

        ...
        // This is what supposedly creates the trigger, 
        // it's apparently not working
        $form.trigger('brandsEnabled');
    }
    else
    {
        // The Module was not found
        throw new Error("Could not find module " + module_id);
    }
});
```

---

```
jQuery(function(){
    
    // Get the Module
    var module_id = 20044;
    var module = EventHandler.getModule(module_id);

    // If a the given Module ID belongs to a defined Module
    if(module)
    {
        var $module = jQuery(module.identifier());
        var $form   = $module.closest('form');

        $form.on('brandsEnabled', function () {

            // THIS EVENT COMES FROM THE PREVIOUS MODULE AND FAILS
            // THE EVENT DOESN'T EVEN REGISTER IN FIREBUG

        })

    }
    else
    {
        // The Module was not found
        throw new Error("Could not find module " + module_id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sadly i can't the application is very complex and uses private CDNs and API connections, i can explain more clearly and provide more details if you need them, basically the issue is just that a jQuery `trigger` doesn't work inside of the `jQuery(function() {})` **modules**.

Comment: i think you have to make simple little example environment to confirm the bug